# Change color of clipped image - Inkscape

Tags: color, inkscape

I clipped a bunch of lines into the shape of a triangle, using the clip function in Inkscape.

I now want to change the color of the remaining triangle which is composed of lines.

I have tried all sorts, but nothing works.

How can I do this? I want to change the color of the entire group/ clipped image. The underlying lines are grouped together if that makes any difference.

I see talk about the clip process being non-destructive - I don't really mind if it is and that helps this process.

Cheers

David

Comment: Hi David, welcome to GD.SE! An image would be helpful (just post a link and someone will edit it in your question). It's just easier to actually see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

You have a triangle and some grouped lines:

[image]

And you clipped the group of lines with the triangle:

[image]

Well, now you can **double click** the clipped group of lines and then draw a bounding box around the original extent of all the lines in order to select them all.

A menu alternative is to select and then right click on the group of lines and choose the menu option at the bottom that says **Enter group #gxxxx**

[image]

And then when you change the stroke colour, all the lines will change colour:

[image]

Note that all the lines are still grouped! It's just that double clicking on the group allows you to temporarily work on individual items within the group, without breaking the group or having to release the clip.

To stop working within the group, select an item and use the menu option **Go to parent**

Finally, even with a group selected, you can still go and set a stroke colour and it will change the strokes of all the items in the group...

Is this what you wanted?